# Determine if a f is a function, surjective or injective.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

How do I determine if these relations are functions, surjectives or injectives?

So here is Question 1:

$\mathbb{f = \{(a, b) ∈ N^2 × N | a ∈ N^2
, a = (a_1, a_2), b, a_1, a_2 ∈ N, b = a_1a_2\}}$

And Question 2:

$\mathbb{f = \{(x, y) ∈ S^2| y = x^2\},\text{ where }S = \{x ∈ R | x ≥ 0\}}$

I am having a lot of trouble trying to figure these two problems out. The problems themselves are very overbearing and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know the definitions of the objects involved?

Comment: @Simone Ramello For question 2, I have found that it is injective, and no, no definitions unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Relation:**

$$\mathbb{f = \{(a, b) ∈ N^2 × N | a ∈ N^2
, a = (a_1, a_2), b, a_1, a_2 ∈ N, b = a_1a_2\}}$$

**Function: Yes**

This one is a function, Because $b=a_1.a_2$ is always unique. It's means that always multiplying two integer numbers result is an unique integer number. So it's a function.

**Surjective: Yes**

Since all numbers in $\mathbb{N}$ is covered by multiplying at least a pair of two integer numbers, so it's a surjective.

**Injectives:No**

Assume that $b=16$ so we may have these possible $a_1$ and $a_2$. 
$$a_1=1 \; a_2=16$$
$$a_1=2 \; a_2=8$$
$$a_1=4 \; a_2=4$$
$$a_1=8 \; a_2=2$$
$$a_1=16 \; a_2=1$$

For all of these we have $b=16$ so this function is not Injectives, since result of multiplying all these pairs will be same and $16$

**Second Relation**

$\mathbb{f = \{(x, y) ∈ S^2| y = x^2\},\text{ where }S = \{x ∈ R | x ≥ 0\}}$

**Function: Yes**

Since result of $x^2=x.x$  is always unique. It's means that for each $x$ we always have a unique result for $y=x^2$.

**Surjective: Yes**

Since it's covers all number in $S = \{x ∈ R | x ≥ 0\}$. Assume there is a real positive number $Y$, since $$X=+\sqrt{Y} \;or\; X=-\sqrt{Y}$$
We must have a positive value for $x$ so $$x=X=+\sqrt{Y}$$.
So this relation is Surjective

**Injectives:Yes**

Since for each $y$ there is only one $x$ so this relation is injectives.